# How to create a key that will sum 2 keys values in Redis

Tags: redis

I have two keys, A= 3 B= 4, how can i create new key C that will be equal to 3+4 (c= 7)?

have tried SET c a+b

'''  SET c a+b '''

Comment: Did you consider using LUA script (EVAL)?  https://redis.io/commands/eval

Answer (score 3):

By using EVAL(Lua interpreter) it will work.,
Command to achieve A+B and set in C,

**EVAL "return redis.call('set','C',redis.call('get','A')+redis.call('get','B'))" 0**

Comment: Thanks i ended up running it from python using INT .

Comment: **NEVER** hardcode key names in a Redis Lua script - **always** pass them with the `KEYS` table.